# Show that PQRS is a parallelogram using vector method. Not using product of vectors.

Tags: vectors

Let $\vec{a}$, $\vec{b}$, $\vec{c}$, $\vec{d}$ be the position vectors of the four distinct points P,Q,R,S respectively. If $\vec{b} - \vec{a}$ = $\vec{c} - \vec{d}$.
Show that PQRS is a parallelogram.

Comment: $ABCD$ is a parallelogram in the plane iff $A+C=B+D$, i.e. iff the midpoints of the diagonals are the same point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity, I will use $P,Q,R,S$ for denoting both the points $P,Q,R,S$ and the vectors $\vec{OP},\vec{OQ},\vec{OR},\vec{OS}$ where $O$ is the origin. With this (useful) abuse of notation, the vector $\vec{PQ}$, for instance, is simply denoted through $Q-P$. In our problem we know that

$$ Q-P = R-S \tag{1}$$
hence $Q-P$ is parallel to $R-S$ and has the same length.
 By rearranging both sides of $(1)$ we also get
$$ Q-R = P-S \tag{2}$$
hence $Q-R$ is parallel to $P-S$ and has the same length.
So, by $(1)$ and $(2)$ it follows that the segments $QP,PS,SR,RQ$ are the sides of a parallelogram.

You may also use my suggestion in the comments: in the plane, $A,B,C,D$ are the vertices of a parallelogram iff the segments $AC$ and $BD$ share the same midpoint, that is the same as requesting that $A+C=B+D$ holds. In your case,
$$ Q+S = R+P \tag{3} $$
is a consequence of $(1)$, too.

Comment: Thank you. From your hint in comment i have already solved it.

Comment: @JohnSr: thanks to you, I am glad to be helpful.

Comment: Sir actually i want to know the procedure behind these type of questions. So its big help if you contribute some part of your knowledge here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2093631/show-that-the-lines-joining-the-mid-points-of-the-consecutive-sides-of-a-quadlit?noredirect=1#comment4303137_2093631

Comment: @JohnSr: I hope my answer to your other question will shed some light.