# Show that the lines joining the mid points of the consecutive sides of a quadliteral form a parallelogram.

Tags: vectors

Using vector method -

Show that the lines joining the mid points of the consecutive sides of a quadliteral form a parallelogram.

The link from which i am taking hint suggest to take one point as origin. But i am unable to understand.

As this question involves use of vectors so problem in taking mid points.

Can someone please explain actual procedure to solve these type of questions.

And i have spent so much time to find solution but no link involve use of vectors. So its become more difficult.

Comment: Do you know how to find the middle point of a segment, given the coordinates of its end points? Do you know how to find the coordinates of a vector, given the coordinates of its origin and end?

Comment: I personally don't even like coordinates in this situation; to travel from vertex $A$ to $B$ we use the vector $\overrightarrow{AB}$; to go from $A$ to the midpoint of the edge $AB$ Is half of the above, i.e., $\frac{1}{2} \overrightarrow{AB}$. If you can find a way to write $\overrightarrow{AB} + \overrightarrow{BC}$ as a single vector (draw!), these two ideas are all you need.

Answer (score 1):

We may use the same Lemma (and the same notation) that was crucial in [your other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2093389/show-that-pqrs-is-a-parallelogram-using-vector-method-not-using-product-of-vect/2093620?noredirect=1#comment4303145_2093620):

> If $A,B,C,D$ are four points in the plane, $ABCD$ is a parallelogram iff $A+C=B+D$.

In the present case, we have four generic points in the plane, $P,Q,R,S$.
 Then the midpoints of the $PQ,QR,RS,SP$ segments are given, respectively, by:
$$ \frac{P+Q}{2},\quad\frac{Q+R}{2},\quad \frac{R+S}{2},\quad\frac{S+P}{2} $$
and is is straightforward to check that
$$ \frac{P+Q}{2}+\frac{R+S}{2} = \frac{Q+R}{2}+\frac{S+P}{2} $$
holds since both terms equal $\frac{P+Q+R+S}{2}$. As a consequence:

> If $A,B,C,D$ are four distinct points in the plane, the midpoints of
>   the segments $AB,BC,CD,DA$ are the vertices of a parallelogram.

Namely, [Varignon's parallelogram](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/Varignon.shtml), whose sides are parallel to the diagonals of $ABCD$.
Remarkably, the area of the Varignon's parallelogram is just half the area of $ABCD$:
[image]

Comment: What is the way or procedure to solve these type of question using vectors?

Comment: @JohnSr: to do mathematics is very seldom a matter of "procedures". You simply need a solid knowledge of basic geometry and a solid knowledge of basic vector manipulations. With a bit of practice, translating statements from a framework to another will become natural, and you will develop the ability to figure out what is an efficient approach for tackling your problems.

Comment: Any link to learn geometry because i am weak in this.

Comment: @JohnSr: thanks to my friend Alexander Bogomolny, this is an *outstanding* resource: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/

Comment: And one last thing can you please edit your answer using vectors.

Comment: I won't do that because I introduced the shortened notation ($A$ in place of $\vec{OA}$, $B-A$ in place of $\vec{AB}$) exactly to avoid typing $\text{\vec}$ too often. Nothing is lost in rigor, so there is no reason to re-introduce the old notation (at least in my humble opinion).

Answer (score 0):

This property is true in any real vector space E ($\Bbb R^2, \Bbb R^3,..., \Bbb R^{666},... $ for example to be simple).

We recall, since we are asked to use vector methods, that a vector is neither more nor less than an element of a vector space. We can limit ourselves to $\Bbb R^3$ if we wish, but it would be a shame to limit ourselves to $\Bbb R^2$.

Let $a,b,c,d$ four points in $E$.

By definition, the midpoint of $ab$ is $x=a+\frac12(b-a)=\frac12(a+b)$; let $y,z,t$ those from $bc, cd, da$.

Then, $y-x=\frac12(b+c)-\frac12(a+b)=\frac12(c-a)$.

And $z-t=\frac12(c+d)-\frac12(a+d)=\frac12(c-a)$.

Then $y-x=z-t$.

Then, by definition, $(x,y,z,t)$ is said to be a parallelogram.